# Order query by day / month / year in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Let me explain want I want to do, I've a table `Clicks` where all clicks for products are saved. And I want to make a graph of how many times something is clicked by customers.

This graph needs a day, month and year view.

What I need for the graph to work is a hash or an object.

My idea is that I'm getting something like:

`data( 2012 => [ 01 => 100, 02 => 300, 03 => 50 etc.], 2011 => [ 01 => 100, 02 => 300, 03 => 50 etc.])`

How can I retrieve all the data from a postgresql database in such an order? I would like to get the `created_at` field and extract the date from there. In a later process, all items from a particular month must be counted.

I'm struggling with this problem quite a bit, could someone push me in the right direction?

Comment: If you can save the total clicks by day, retrieving the total by month and year becomes trivial, as you just sum up the total clicks for 30, 31, 365, 366 days.

Comment: Would you like to simply describe the schema for your database, or should we imaginatively cobble-up names for the fields and tables? And, how about showing us a sample of the code you've written so we don't reinvent your particular wheel?

Comment: The fields from the database are "user_id", "product_id", "created_at", "updated_at".

When there is nothing to display, the graph will display 0.

What i wanted to do is:

Clicks.where('user_id = ?', current_user.id).count .. This counts all the clicks form this user, but not in a period of time.

From an other question here at stackoverflow, i get: 

@clicks = Click.select('count(distinct(id)) as id, year(created_at) as y, month(created_at) as m').group('y, m').where({:user_id => current_user.id})

But this break at the year(created_at)

Comment: Also tried the following:

@clicks = Click.where({:user_id => current_user.id}).count(:group => "strftime('%m',date")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The snippet you posted is for MySQL - to do the same in PostgreSQL:

```
@clicks = Click.select("count(*) as c, date_part('year', created_at) as y, date_part('month', created_at) as m").
                group("y", "m").
                where({:user_id => current_user.id})
```

This will give you a hash in the format `[year, month] => count`.  To get it in the format you wanted, you'll need to tweak the results a bit:

```
results = @clicks.inject({}) do |m, kv|
  year, month = kv.first
  clicks = kv.last
  m[year] ||= {}
  m[year][month] = clicks
  m
end
```

Or a bit more concise:

```
results = @clicks.each_with_object({}) do |((year, month), clicks), m|
  (m[year] ||= {})[month] = clicks
end
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Postgree(or Heroku whit PG) can make this way:

by Month:

```
Consumer.all.order("extract(month from created_at) DESC")
```

by Day

```
Consumer.all.order("extract(day from created_at) DESC")
```

by Year

```
Consumer.all.order("extract(year from created_at) DESC")
```